# Projective tensor product of operator spaces

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, tensor-products, c-star-algebras, operator-spaces

Consider the following fragment from Effros and Ruan's book "Operator spaces"

[image]

Why is a decomposition as in the red box possible? In fact, it is not even clear to me that any such decomposition is possible! But I don't have a lot of intuition about the Kronecker product of matrices. I am guessing some explicit construction here exists.

Any help or hints is highly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why $u\in M_n(V\otimes W)$ can be written as $u=\alpha(v\otimes w)\beta$? Or why you can choose the norms as stated?

Comment: @MaoWao Both are my questions, but if you can answer one of them I am also glad :)

Comment: Choosing the norms is just a standard rescaling trick: You can find $\alpha,\beta,v,w$ so that $\lVert \alpha\rVert\lVert\beta\rVert\lVert v\rVert\lVert w\rVert\leq \lVert u\rVert_\wedge+\epsilon$ by definition of the projective tensor product norm, and then you can rescale $\alpha$, $\beta$ to have norm one by pushing the scalar factor onto $v\otimes w$.

Comment: Writing $u$ as $\alpha(v\otimes w)\beta$ is a bit messy notationwise, so I won't give a full answer. Basically, $u$ can be written as $\sum_j u_j^{(1)}\otimes u_j^{(2)}$. Then take $v$ to be the matrix whose first row is $u^{(1)}$ and the rest is zero, $w$ the matrix whose first row is $u^{(2)}$ and the rest is zero. The Kronecker tensor product $v\otimes w$ will have in the first row all possible products $u_j^{(1)}\otimes u_k^{(2)}$. Then you can pick out the entries $j=k$ by multiplying from the right with a column matrix which has $1$ in the $j=k$ position and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: That is for $u\in V\otimes W$, but the matrix-valued case $u\in M_n(V\otimes W)$ is similar.

Comment: @MaoWao I understand that you did not want to write these details down haha. Thanks, got the idea! If you want you can make this into an answer.

Comment: I wrote an answer for the smallest non-trivial case. It is a bit annoying that the whole notation is so clumsy and there seems to be non efficient way to write it with indices (because of the implicit isomorphism $M_p\otimes M_q\cong M_{pq}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is how it works for $u=v_1\otimes w_1+v_2\otimes w_1$ with $v_1,v_2\in V$, $w_1,w_2\in W$. In this case let
$$
v=\begin{pmatrix}v_1&v_2\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\;w=\begin{pmatrix}w_1&w_2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have (well, there is some choice in the isomorphism $M_2\otimes M_2\cong M_4$)
$$
v\otimes w=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\otimes w_1&v_2\otimes w_1&v_1\otimes w_2&v_2\otimes w_2\\0\otimes w_1&0\otimes w_1&0\otimes w_2&0\otimes w_2\\v_1\otimes 0&v_2\otimes 0&v_1\otimes 0&v_2\otimes 0\\0\otimes 0&0\otimes 0&0\otimes 0&0\otimes 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}v_1\otimes w_1&v_2\otimes w_1&v_1\otimes w_2&v_2\otimes w_2\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
With
$$
\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\,\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
we get
$$
\alpha(v\otimes w)\beta=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v_1\otimes w_1+v_2\otimes w_2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}=v_1\otimes w_1+v_2\otimes w_2.
$$
For sums of more than two elementary tensors and elements of $M_n(V\otimes W)$ the idea is the same, just that things get real ugly to write down.

To get elements $\alpha,\beta,v,w$ with the desired norm, first note that by definition of the norm they can be chosen such that $\lVert \alpha\rVert\lVert v\rVert\lVert w\rVert\lVert\beta\rVert\leq \lVert u\rVert_\wedge+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. Then one can use the multilinearity of the expression to rescale it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you are interested and/or have time, here is another question about operator spaces: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763007/completion-of-operator-space