# Completion of operator space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, complete-spaces, operator-spaces

**Definition**: An (abstract) [operator space](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/wittstock/OperatorSpace/node3.html) is a linear space $X$ together with a sequence $\{\|\cdot\|_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of norms such that

- $\|x\oplus y\|_{m+n}= \max\{\|x\|_m, \|y\|_n\}$ for $x\in M_m(X), y \in M_n(X)$.
- $\|\alpha x \beta\|_n \le \|\alpha\|\|x\|_m\|\beta\|$ for $\alpha \in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{C}), x \in M_m(X), \beta \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{C})$.

I now want to understand what the completion $Y$ of the operator space $X$ is, in a way that $Y$ becomes an operator space.

The first step should be to begin to define $Y$ to be the Banach space completion of $X$. To define an operator space structure on $Y$, we still require norms on
$$M_2(Y), M_3(Y), M_4(Y), \dots$$
and it is not clear to me how to do this with the definition of abstract operator spaces.

If we use the concrete operator space approach (Ruan's theorem), then we can choose a Hilbert space $H$ and a complete isometry
$$\sigma: X \to B(H).$$
We can then define $Y =  \overline{\sigma(X)}\subseteq B(H)$ which shows that the Banach space completion of $X$ carries the canonical structure of an operator space (of course, it should be shown that this does not depend on the choice of representation and stuff like that). I would like to know if there is a way to avoid Ruan's theorem?

To illustrate where such a situation as in this question may happen: if $X,Y$ are operator spaces, then one can define norms on $M_n(X \odot Y)$ (where $X\odot Y$ is the algebraic tensor product) which satisfy the two requirements above. Thus, $X\odot Y$ becomes an abstract operator space. But then one defines the projective tensor product $X\hat{\otimes} Y$ to be the completion of this space (whatever this means).

Comment: +1 but which norm does one choose on $M_{p,q}(\Bbb C)?$

Comment: (Naive idea) Take the closure of $X$ in its bidual? (Is the latter naturally an operator space?)

Comment: @AnneBauval I assume this is the usual operatornorm of matrices, anything else wouldn't make much make sense.

Comment: @AnneBauval The dual of an operator space has a natural operator space structure, so the bidual does too. In this was, we have a complete isometry $X\to X^{**}$. Maybe this indeed gives a way to prove this!

Comment: Which (of the many) "operatonorm of matrices"? I mean, relative to which norms on $\Bbb C^p,\Bbb C^q?$

Comment: @AnneBauval Viewing $m\times n$ matrices as linear maps $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^m$, the operator norm induced by the Euclidean norm (= $\|\cdot\|_2$) on domain and codomain. For $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, this gives the unique norm that turns it into a $C^*$-algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial ingredient is that the uniform structure on $M_n(X)$ is already determined by the norm on $X$, there is only a choice in the isometric structure. More precisely, if $[a_{ij}]\in M_n(X)$, then
$$
\max_{i,j}\lVert a_{ij}\rVert\leq \lVert [a_{ij}]\rVert\leq \sum_{i,j}\lVert a_{ij}\rVert.
$$
This can be seen from the abstract definition of an operator space as follows:

For one, $\|a_{kl}\|=\|E_{1k}[a_{ij}] E_{l1}\|\leq \lVert E_{1i}\rVert\lVert [a_{ij}]\rVert\lVert E_{j1}\rVert=\lVert[a_{ij}]\rVert$. For the second inequality, we have
$$
\lVert [a_{ij}]\rVert=\left\lVert \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\otimes E_{ij}\right\rVert\leq \sum_{i,j}\lVert E_{i1}(a_{ij}\otimes E_{11})E_{1j}\rVert\leq \sum_{i,j}\lVert a_{ij}\oplus 0_{n-1}\rVert\leq \sum_{i,j}\lVert a_{ij}\rVert.
$$
Thus $M_n(Y)$ contains $M_n(X)$ as a dense subspace (with respect to this uniform structure, no norm is chosen yet). Then we can define the norm on $M_n(Y)$ simply by identifying it with the normed completion of $M_n(X)$.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! This definitely cleared things up for me. The uniqueness of an operator space structure on $Y$ is shown in this answer. In my answer, I try to explain why it exists.

Comment: As I said, you get existence of an operator space structure by extending the norms on $M_n(X)$ to their completion $M_n(Y)$. From the estimates in this answer it is clear that the operator space axioms are preserved.

Comment: But you assume that the completion of $M_n(X)$ is $M_n(Y)$, and this is a priori not clear to me.

Comment: But this follows from the description of the uniform structure (that was essentially the point): $M_n(X)$ embeds into $M_n(Y)$ (this is injective because it is injective in every matrix entry), and $M_n(X)$ is dense in $M_n(Y)$ with respect to the uniform structure (simply approximate in each matrix entry). Thus $M_n(Y)$ as uniform space is the completion of $M_n(X)$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand, as I'm not familiar with these uniform structures. Will learn about this.

Comment: Another way to say this, and probablby quite useful to keep in mind if you're not familiar with uniform spaces: For any fixed $n$, any two norms on $M_n(X)$ coming from abstract operator norm structures are equivalent (of course the equivalence constants usually blow up as $n\to\infty$). Clearly, $M_n(Y)$ is the completion of $M_n(X)$ in the norm $\max_{i,j}\lVert a_{ij}\rVert$. But then it is also the completion of $M_n(X)$ in the matrix norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_n$, since completions (up to isomorphism) are the same for equivalent norms.

Comment: That's definitely a nice perspective! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**: If $X$ is an operator space, there exists a unique operator space structure on the Banach space completion $Y$ of $X$ such that the norms of $M_n(Y)$ restrict to the norms of $M_n(X)$ (i.e. such that $X$ becomes an operator subsystem of $Y$).

**Proof**: Uniqueness (as suggested by MaoWao's answer):

Convergence in $M_n(Y)$ is equivalent with convergence of all entries in $Y$ (see the other answer). From this, it easily follows that $M_n(X)$ is norm-dense in $M_n(Y)$. Thus, there is only one possible extension of the norm of $M_n(X)$ to a norm on $M_n(Y)$.

Existence:

- Abstract operator space approach (as suggested in the comments above): We can embed $X$ completely isometrically into its bidual $X^{**}$ using the canonical map. The closure $Y$ of $X$ inside $X^{**}$ (which is a model for the Banach space completion of $X$) inherits a desired operator space structure.
- Concrete operator space approach: Choose a Hilbert space $H$ and a complete isometry $X \subseteq B(H)$. Then $Y:= \overline{X}\subseteq B(H)$ does what we want.